# Browsersync with modrewrite does not work with query which contains special characters

Tags: angularjs, apache, mod-rewrite, browser-sync

I am developing an angular application and I'm having an issue with refreshing a page with url that contains special characters like dot.

I use browsersync with modRewrite module.  The below is my script:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    modRewrite  = require('connect-modrewrite');

browserSync.init(files, {
    startPath: '/',
    server: {
       middleware: [
         modRewrite([
            '!\\.\\w+$ /index.html [L]'
         ]) 
       ]
    }
});
```

With this setting, when I refresh a page with url - "localhost:7000/blocker?email=test@gmail.com",  I get "Cannot GET /blocker?email=test@bespoke.is"

I believe I can fix this issue by configuring modRewrite script but so far all the scripts I tried didn't fix the issue.

It would be great if anyone can help me out here. Thanks!